# If statement logic error

Tags: c++, if-statement, struct, int

```
if ((pCommandPts>=tempChar.commandValue) && ((pCommandPts - tempChar.commandValue)<=0))
```

If pCommandPts is an int with the value 6 and tempChar.commandValue is an int with the value 3, why would this statement evaluate to false?

Comment: Well, `pCommandPts - tempChar.commandValue` is 6-3, which is 3, which isn't less than or equal to 0. The overall condition only evaluates to true if both the left and right operands of the `&&` operator are true. Why would you expect it to evaluate to true?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - of course it isn't thank you for pointing out the error - must be going as blind as a bat.

Answer (score 2):

Left part of this expression is true in case of `6` and `3`, but `6-3` is not lower or equal to zero

`&& ((pCommandPts - tempChar.commandValue)<=0))`

Answer (score 2):

That code makes no sense, and it's almost certainly a bug.

If you rearrange the inequalities, you get:

```
 a >= b && a <= b
```

Which is only true if `a == b`, which is not true for your case `6 != 3`